# Kusto / KQL - Create new rows between 1st row(startdate) and 2nd row (end date) then fill value using startdate and stop before end date

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i want to create new rows where in it applies the value most recent log between 2 timeframes. i tried using a make list to create a new row but i dont know how to do a make list if i have 2 or more diffrenct ranges. (sample: location 1 Jan-22 to Jun-22, location 2 Feb-22 to Jun-22)

please consider also that there will be more Site,Class,Datestamp variables.

The data loooks like this

```
datatable (Site: string,Class: string, Rating: int ,datestamp: datetime)    
 [         
 'Location 1',  'A', 5, '2022-06-30T00:00:00Z',
 'Location 1',  'A', 10, '2021-01-30T00:00:00Z',
 'Location 2',  'A', 4, '2022-06-30T00:00:00Z',
 'Location 2',  'A', 3, '2021-02-28T00:00:00Z',
 ]
```

This would be the final output

```
Site    Class   Rating  Datestamp
Location 1  A   5   2022-06-30T00:00:00Z
Location 1  A   5   2022-05-30T00:00:00Z
Location 1  A   5   2022-04-30T00:00:00Z
Location 1  A   5   2022-03-31T00:00:00Z
Location 1  A   5   2022-02-30T00:00:00Z
Location 1  A   10  2021-01-31T00:00:00Z
Location 2  A   4   2022-06-30T00:00:00Z
Location 2  A   4   2022-05-30T00:00:00Z
Location 2  A   4   2022-04-30T00:00:00Z
Location 2  A   4   2022-03-31T00:00:00Z
Location 2  A   3   2021-02-28T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: Please fix your data sample

Answer (score 2):

```
datatable (Site: string,Class: string, Rating: int ,datestamp: datetime)    
 [         
     'Location 1' ,'A' ,5  ,'2022-06-30T00:00:00Z'
    ,'Location 1' ,'A' ,10 ,'2022-01-30T00:00:00Z'
    ,'Location 2' ,'A' ,4  ,'2022-06-30T00:00:00Z'
    ,'Location 2' ,'A' ,3  ,'2022-02-28T00:00:00Z'
 ] 
 |  partition hint.strategy=native by Site
    (
            order by    datestamp asc
        |   extend      prev_datestamp = prev(datestamp) 
    )
|   extend          months_diff     = datetime_diff('month', datestamp, prev_datestamp)
|   mv-expand       months_offset   = range(1, months_diff, 1) to typeof(int)
|   extend          datestamp       = coalesce(startofday(endofmonth(datetime_add('month', months_offset, prev_datestamp))), datestamp)
|   project-away    prev_datestamp, months_offset, months_diff
```

| Site | Class | Rating | datestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location 1 | A | 10 | 2022-01-30T00:00:00Z |
| Location 1 | A | 5 | 2022-02-28T00:00:00Z |
| Location 1 | A | 5 | 2022-03-31T00:00:00Z |
| Location 1 | A | 5 | 2022-04-30T00:00:00Z |
| Location 1 | A | 5 | 2022-05-31T00:00:00Z |
| Location 1 | A | 5 | 2022-06-30T00:00:00Z |
| Location 2 | A | 3 | 2022-02-28T00:00:00Z |
| Location 2 | A | 4 | 2022-03-31T00:00:00Z |
| Location 2 | A | 4 | 2022-04-30T00:00:00Z |
| Location 2 | A | 4 | 2022-05-31T00:00:00Z |
| Location 2 | A | 4 | 2022-06-30T00:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41RTU+DQBC9N+l/mBtLshigagxJD8arJ/WkMc2WHVpMYcnupJbEH+9A6dIPjQ4Edibz3sx7qxXxs9wgiOeSMANHtqxX8mGjnPMZPCnifwZlTSC1InSkqiaD7khlhSFwTCfwBofgpIvg0eSMNTUkAcjgnj83wIc0TtMovo1m8UscZ/37Guwx8gdMEntM8gcmPWCu/z/HY2YjJo3Su1PMeyfqC6BRlsoet2Y/rtgjdmHVzmsm2yIsW+is3A8Rgw9DGKvRdh0c3kZQLh/beADgjrDW+7yxuF2MvfO+IHwhHJwOp5NzZBeVqWntFrosij6f+yvrayLoGwI5biPPJg7E1TbCXaM890BsisIh9cRW1SsUiTyeKSEJgQxQ26ApBNv1y56jQBj2zI3aoMtRcNmSKbRqBUNM0dMLL0NpPao42epCSRge6RwWaaz5wJwi9anaS7svGI+0fQPYSGiFOwMAAA==)

Comment: Kind reminder to check the answer